# Impossible to inherit from this object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, box2d, private-constructor

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482998/best-way-to-deal-with-object-that-cant-instantiate-itself), people have suggested I go with "option 3" which might look like this:

```
class b2Body {
private:
    b2Body() {}
    friend class b2World;
};

class Body : public b2Body {
private:
    Body() {}
    friend class World;
};

class b2World {
public:
    b2Body *CreateBody() {
        return new b2Body;
    }
};

class World : public b2World {
public:
    Body *CreateBody() {
        return new Body;
    }
};

int main() {
    World w;
    Body *b = w.CreateBody();
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online](http://codepad.org/Gbnmvn4P)

But there are two major problems with this:

1. `Body` can never be constructed, even with `World::CreateBody` (because `b2Body` is private)
2. Even if it could, then the `b2Body` part wouldn't be initialized correctly (`b2World::CreateBody` *needs* to be called)

Does this mean I can never inherit from `b2Body`/`b2World` and follow this same design pattern? (keep in mind that I can't edit the b2* classes)

If so, I suppose you guys would recommend I just keep `b2World` and `b2Body` as member variables instead?

---

I think it comes down to these two options now:

- [option 3c](http://codepad.org/CXufhOiY)
- [option 2](http://codepad.org/KminPIN5)

Answer (score 2):

Only `b2World` can create a `b2Body` so this just doesn't go anywhere. These classes clearly aren't designed to be inherited from so yes, aggregate them instead. What about something along the lines of

```
class Body {
public:
    Body( b2Body* b ) : b2b( b ) {}

private:
    b2Body*const b2b;
};

class World {
public:
    World() : b2w( /* create b2w here */ ) {}

    Body *CreateBody() {
            return new Body( b2w->CreateBody( /*...*/ ); }
    }
private:
    b2World*const b2w;
};
```